# Android custom rating bar image size problem

Tags: android

Iam building a custom rating bar. With help of kozyr's article i have created it.
But i have an issue with different image scaling sizes for different screen types.
Below i provide image with screenshots of my custom rating bar in the left, and simple imageview to the right.
This is for HVGA screen.

[link to screenshot](http://habreffect.ru/files/d78/db1c15f32/HVGA.png)

As you see, stars in rating bar and in the imageview are the same

And this screenshot from HVGA screen

[another link to the screenshot](http://habreffect.ru/files/5da/48c9d42e0/WVGA.png)

Android somehow resizes stars in my ratingbar. What is the problem?!!

Here is the code

```
<RatingBar android:id="@+id/rating_lunch" style="@style/starRatingBar" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:numStars="5" android:stepSize="1.0"/>
```

Here goes the style:

```
<style name="starRatingBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.RatingBar">
    <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/progress_star_big</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">19px</item>
    <item name="android:maxHeight">19px</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved. When i added

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4"
      android:targetSdkVersion="7"   />
```

to the manifest file everything became allright)

Answer (score 2):

Try using *device independent* pixels instead of actual pixels. e.g.:

```
<item name="android:maxHeight">19dp</item>
```

See [the docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) on this topic.

Comment: unfortunately, it does not helps