# Android ratingbar size (cant use Widget.RatingBar.Small)

Tags: android, xml, size, custom-component

Helo,

I've created a custom ratingbar by using to following tutorial: http://kozyr.zydako.net/2010/05/23/pretty-ratingbar/

But now i want to resize my custom rating stars to smaller stars..

i got:

```
        <style name="orangeRatingBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.RatingBar">
           <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/orange_ratingbar</item>
           <item name="android:minHeight">14dip</item>
           <item name="android:maxHeight">14dip</item>
        </style>
```

When i set the minHeight and the maxHeight i see only part of the stars.. 
The star image is 14px height and 14 width. Why do i only see a part of the image when i set the minheight 14px or 14dip.. When i set it on 19dip i see the whole star..

How can i create smaller stars (the size of default small ratingBar)?

Answer (score 2):

For custom Stars size in your ratingbar use this tag in XML-

for small-`style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"`

for large-`style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyle"`

for medium-`style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleIndicator"`

Answer (score 0):

I came across this previously

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4"
  android:targetSdkVersion="7"   />
```

You might find more info here
 [Android custom rating bar image size problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5864478/android-custom-rating-bar-image-size-problem)